# how to attach multiple files to email client in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using `Intent .ACTION_SEND` to get default email client. It works fine but now  i need to attach more than one file to email.

`email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,...)` attaches only last uri added to it.

So can I attach multiple files? I think this can be done by using `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. Here is the code I am trying:

```
String uri=getScreenShot();

Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.setType("application/octet-stream");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri));
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:"+csvpath));
            alert.dismiss();
            ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That works:

```
final Intent ei = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
ei.setType("plain/text");
ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"me@somewhere.nodomain"});
ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "That one works");
```

then add files' uris:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

ei.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ei, "Sending multiple attachment"), 12345);
```

Comment: Note that there is a risk of getting your google account disabled if you send mails with multiple attachments and spam-like text, from gmail. Try to use a development account when trying this.

Comment: It is working only for the first time. When i sending the 2 mail simultaneously it works only for 1 time.

Comment: ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE does the job :)

Comment: i am getting images from my assets folder can u please help me how will i get multiple images using this line Uri theUri = Uri.parse("content://com.jamia.binoria/"+fatwaImageArray); may i need to get all images and put it in ArrayList?

Comment: ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE did not work for me. I change only that in my code (from ACTION_SENDTO), and when the intent menu opens up it says "No apps can perform this action." Is any of the other code listed here necessary to send muliple file in an email?

Comment: It works only if I use this:
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

Answer (score 9):

You can use
`putParcelableArrayListExtra` method of 
Intent as shown below. Instead of
using like this: `email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri));`, you can use an
`ArrayList` as shown below:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
//convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
for (String file : filePaths)
{
    File fileIn = new File(file);
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
    uris.add(u);
}
email.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

Comment: yup i did this but it gives nullpointerexception on opening gmail client. upon opening up the default email client  it does not show any attachment.

Comment: @N-JOY did you find any solution?

Comment: @TalhaÇ Did you try the accepted answer? Probably that will work

Comment: @N-JOY didn't work for my case.

Answer (score 4):

Worked For Me

```
 Intent emailIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, Uri.parse("mailto:"+ clientEmail));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"working-tutor-form From App");
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file://" +  URI1);
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("file://" +  URI2);
                Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("file://" +  URI3);
                ArrayList<Uri> arrayList=new ArrayList<Uri>();
                arrayList.add(uri1);
                arrayList.add(uri2);
                arrayList.add(uri3);
                emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,arrayList);

                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,body);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send Via..."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is function that will do the job :)

```
public static void sendEmailMulipleFiles(Context context, String toAddress, String subject, String body, ArrayList<String> attachmentPath) throws Exception {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { toAddress });
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        ResolveInfo best = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.contains(".gm.") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail"))
                best = info;
        }
        ArrayList<Uri> uri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        for (int i = 0; i < attachmentPath.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(attachmentPath.get(i));
            uri.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
        }

        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);


        if (best != null)
            intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);

        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an email application..."));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Man! You did! i wasted time with lots of not working codes! Finally your code is working! Thanks a loT!

Answer (score 0):

After 1 day work finally I am able to attach multiple image files from \sdcard\accident\ folder to email client. For attaching multiple files I had to add the images to the ContentResolver which is responsible for gallery images provider.
Here is the Complete Code ---

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"soubhabpathak2010@gmail.com"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Accident Capture");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);

ArrayList<Uri> uriList = getUriListForImages();
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);
Log.d(TAG, "Size of the ArrayList :: " +uriList.size());
FormHolderActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

So there is no change in the First Section of Code -- But Change is in getUriListForImages() method which is as follows---

```
    private ArrayList<Uri> getUriListForImages() throws Exception {
                ArrayList<Uri> myList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                String imageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/accident/";
                File imageDirectory = new File(imageDirectoryPath);
                String[] fileList = imageDirectory.list();
                if(fileList.length != 0) {
                    for(int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++)
                    {   
                        try 
                        {   
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
                            values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, fileList[i]);
                            values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileList[i]);
                            values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, new Date().getTime());
                            values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                            values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, imageDirectoryPath.hashCode());
                            values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, fileList[i]);
                            values.put("_data", imageDirectoryPath + fileList[i]);
                            ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                            Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                            myList.add(uri);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return myList;
            }
```

This is working fine and I am able to attach multiple image files to emulator default email client and send then successfully .