# How can I share two or more audio files at the same time?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that shares audio files by WhatsApp, email, etc. My code works for one single file, but it does not work for two or more files at the same time.
This is my code:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("audio/*");

for (i=0;i<completepath.size();i++)
{
    File send=new File(completepath.get(i));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(send));
}

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send audio "));
```

Comment: What kind of errors/outcome do you get when you try to share two files at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

There is the additional send command for `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` that you can take advantage of within the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).

This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552831/how-to-attach-multiple-files-to-email-client-in-android) gives an idea of the process behind the use of the intent from another relevant post.