# Sending mail with attachment in android

Tags: android

I am trying to send a with attachment where the attachment file could be any type of file(like txt,image,pdf etc) from a sd card.
I used these

```
String filelocation="file:/"+attachment_file_path1.getText().toString();    
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// set the type to 'email'
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
String to[] = {"destination@yahoo.com"};
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "bodyyyyyyyyy");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filelocation));
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my mail");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
```

N:B: if i print the `attachment_file_path1.getText().toString()` it shows like "/storage/sdcard0/myfolder/my.txt"

my email is sent to the destination but my attachment is not sent. 
How can i solve the problem??

Comment: which error your getting? post some log messages

Comment: If you use `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` to send attachment(s), use `emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachments);` where `attachments` must be of `ArrayList<Uri>` object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552831/how-to-attach-multiple-files-to-email-client-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Change your `emailIntent.setType(text/plain)` to `emailIntent.setType("*/*")` for allowing to send any file type.

Answer (score 0):

Path format is :

*file:///sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg*

you need the extra / as this points to the root directory, i.e.:

file:// + /sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg

combined as

*file:///sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg*

In the above snippet you need:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+ sPhotoFileName));
```